# Pojo validation works. Poko (kotlin) doesn't. Why?

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-data, spring-data-rest, bean-validation

I have a POJO and have JSR validation enabled.

For demonstration reasons I have completely reimplemented an entire project as Kotlin and I would like to demonstrate the validation aspect. Except, in Kotlin it simply doesn't work and it's not obvious why. Can someone explain what I am missing?

Java to enable validation:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public static class ValidationConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    private final Validator jsr303Validator;

    @Override
    public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingListener) {
        //bean validation always before save and create
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", jsr303Validator);
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeSave", jsr303Validator);

    }


}
```

POJO:

```
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Employee implements Identifiable<Long>{


    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9]+")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 32)
    private String name;

    @Email
    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @PastOrPresent
    private LocalDate hireDate = LocalDate.now();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Form> forms = Collections.emptyList();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Report> reports = Collections.emptyList();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    public Employee(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Employee(String name) {
        this(name,name +"@sterlingts.com");
    }
}
```

Kotlin validation code:

```
@Configuration
 class ValidationConfiguration(private val jsr303Validator: Validator) : RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {
    override fun configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(validatingListener: ValidatingRepositoryEventListener) {
        //bean validation always before save and create
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", jsr303Validator)
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeSave", jsr303Validator)

    }
}
```

POKO:

```
@Entity
data class Employee(@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9]+")
                    @Size(min = 6, max = 32)
                    val name: String,
                    @Email
                    @NotNull
                    val email: String?,
                    @PastOrPresent
                    val hireDate: LocalDate = LocalDate.now(),

                    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
                    val forms:List<Form> = listOf(),
                    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
                    val reports:List<Report> = listOf(),
                    @Id @GeneratedValue( strategy =  GenerationType.IDENTITY) private val id: Long? = null): Identifiable<Long> {

    override fun getId() = id

    constructor(name:String): this(name,"$name@sterlingts.com")
}
```

example:

> POST /employees

```
{
 "name": "christian",
 "email": "This is not an email"
}
```

result (java version as expected):

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "entity": "Employee",
      "property": "email",
      "invalidValue": "This is not an email",
      "message": "must be a well-formed email address"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, as a Kotlin Poko:

> POST /employees

```
{
 "name": "christian",
 "email": "This is not an email"
}
```

result (201 Created):

```
{
  "name" : "christian",
  "email" : "This is not an email",
  "hireDate" : "2018-02-26",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/employees/19"
    },
    "employee" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/employees/19"
    },
    "forms" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/employees/19/forms"
    },
    "reports" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/employees/19/reports"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `data class A(@Email val email: String)`, the annotation is applied to the constructor parameter by default. In other words it's equivalent to:

```
class A{
  public A(@Email String email) { ... }
}
```

In your case you want the annotation to be applied to the field, so you need to write:

```
data class A(@field:Email val email: String)
```

More about annotations in [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets).